# taking backup of code signing identities for a new mac

Tags: ios, xcode7, codesign

I need to take backup of the code signing identities to shift to a new mac, I have found two ways to do so.

1. As per the apple develper docs, I can take a backup of code signing identities by going to preferences - > accounts -> settings -> export developer accounts (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW16)
2. By going to keychain access and exporting the private keys.

There is inconsistency between the ios distribution certificate info in keychain access and in xcode. When I view details of my team in xcode, the iOS developer signing identity is fine, but the distribution signing identity shows me reset button. I see this distribution certificate in keychain access and it says it is valid (with a green tick).

[image: As it shows in the xcode] 
[image: As it shows in keychain access]

I have already released an app using this distribuition certificate, and I wouldn't want any problems while releasing updates to it. Will resetting before taking the backup hinder the updates by invalidating the private key?

Thanks,
Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

In `Preferences...` > `Accounts` tab, there is `settings` icon in the left column. When you click icon you'll find `Export Developer Accounts`. Store the profile somewhere on `Cloud`, or other PC.

On another mac, You can import this.

Comment: what about the iOS distribution certificate ?

Comment: It will import everything - certificate, provisioning profile etc. Let me give you an example. A day my mac stopped working (was not starting). I went to the store, they said it must be formatted and worst thing is that data cannot be restored. When I installed Xcode, problem came with the certs & profiles. But I came to ind that I had mailed my developer profile to my colleague. I tried using it. And Ahhh, it was working, everything was restored.